# How do I join two grouped up SELECT Querys in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

There are just two relations important for this:

1. geoLake with Name and Country
2. geoMountain with Name and Country

Both relations having couple hundreds of Entries.

**The Task is to just display the names of the countrys which have more lakes than mountains.**

```
SELECT m.Country, Count(m.Country)
FROM geoMountain m
GROUP BY m.Country
```

Shows a list with all Countrynames and the Number of how many Mountains are related to each country.

```
SELECT l.Country, Count(l.Country)
FROM  geoLake l
GROUP BY l.Country
```

Having the same Output for how many Lakes are in every Country.

I tried like everthing to bring this two grouped relations together, but not having any success and kinda stucked after like 2 hours, because I am running out of ideas.

How do I bring this together?

My specific Questions:

Is it possible to get a Relation like:

```
+--------+-------------------+----------------+
|Country |COUNT(m.Country)   |COUNT(l.Country)|
+--------+-------------------+----------------+
|Country1|How many Mountains |How many Lakes  |
|Country2|How many Mountains |How many Lakes  |
[...]
```

And how do I add a SELECT query on top of this with this

```
SELECT Country FROM What is build up there WHERE COUNT(m.Country)  > COUNT(l.Country)
```

mechanic.

PS. Hope my question is understandable, english isn't my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH
-- count the amount of mountains
cte1 AS (
    SELECT m.Country, Count(m.Country) cnt
    FROM geoMountain m
    GROUP BY m.Country
),
-- count the amount of lakes
cte2 AS (
    SELECT l.Country, Count(l.Country) cnt
    FROM  geoLake l
    GROUP BY l.Country
),
-- gather countries which are mentioned in at least one table
cte3 AS (
    SELECT Country FROM cte1
    UNION
    SELECT Country FROM cte2
)
-- get needed data
SELECT Country, 
       COALESCE(cte1.cnt, 0) AS MountainsAmount,
       COALESCE(cte2.cnt, 0) AS LakesAmount
-- join data to complete countries list
FROM cte3
LEFT JOIN cte2 USING (Country)
LEFT JOIN cte1 USING (Country)
-- HAVING MountainsAmount > LakesAmount
;
```

Comment: @TrizZm4ster Uncomment HAVING and adjust the condition.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! It is working nearly. When I add 'HAVING MountainsAmount > LakesAmount' its saying,  MountainsAmount does not exist.

Comment: The HAVING clause only works if the query it is being used in is GROUPed. Try a regular WHERE clause instead.

Comment: @TrizZm4ster *its saying, MountainsAmount does not exist.* ?? What is **precise** MySQL version? Show output for `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: @e_i_pi This is not correct in MySQL.

Comment: @Akina You sure about that? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f2aFwPYkvwEpykiRKJGC6U/0

Comment: Up to  the LEFT JOINS I get a TABLE as shown in my Questionpost. Perfect. But when I use the HAVING clause I get the error:  Column MountainsAmount doesnt exist. The Version is PostgreSQL 14.1 compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit.

Comment: @e_i_pi its working with the where clause! Thanks to both of you - You saved me. And I did learn something cause I now know how the With-Clause is working. Still tryna understand the COALESCE(cte1.cnt, 0). Can someone explan what it does?

Comment: @e_i_pi *You sure about that?* About what? About the fact that the expressions in WHERE will solve? this is true. About the fact that HAVING is legal in MySQL, and the statement "The HAVING clause **only** works if the query it is being used in is GROUPed." is not correct for MySQL? true too.

Comment: @TrizZm4ster *when I use the HAVING clause I get the error: Column MountainsAmount doesnt exist. The Version is PostgreSQL 14.1 compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit.* :facepalm: You do not see then difference between the words "MySQL" and "PostgreSQL"??? They're two absolutely different DBMSs!!! the solution applicable for one of them can be incorrect in another one easily.

Comment: Oh, good to know - thought SQL is SQL. Just startet this like a week ago.

Comment: @TrizZm4ster Yes, SQL is SQL always. But any DBMS' SQL contains 50% of SQL extensions which are individual.